# node command vs app.listen()

Tags: node.js, express, koa

I'm confused.  So if I use gulp-develop-server, it's got a app.listen():

**gulpfile.js**

```
config.server.path is set to './app,js'

server = require('gulp-develop-server');

gulp.task('default', ['server:start'], function(){
});

gulp.task('server:start', function() {
    server.listen({ path: config.server.path});
});
```

My **app.js** has this:

```
var koa = require('koa')();

koa.listen(config.server.port, function(){
    console.log('Koa app is listening on port ' + config.server.port);
});
```

so I'm trying to understand better how node is being started.  I see people mention doing it manually like "node app.js".  So doesn't koa.listen() automatically do a "node" command to start the koa web server?  If I use gulp-develop-server and specify server.listen, isn't that doing 2 server.listen() for node?

Just trying to understand the basics here and can't understand why anyone would manually type in 'node [file with .listen]' manually.  I'm not doing that manually and server.listen() obviously uses the 'node' command on my app.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gulpfile is a Node script. So when you run `gulp server:start` you're executing a Node application, the `gulp` command is essentially `node` plus some extra functionality.

The way gulp-develop-server works is it runs an additional Node application as a child process. `server.listen` is basically just telling gulp-develop-server what script to run.

The naming is a little confusing, but essentially what's going on is: You have 2 Node applications running on your machine (one that you can see, and one in the background), but only 1 server.